# jQuery Mobile Hash Navigation not Working On Mobile Devices?

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-mobile

When I run a jQuery Mobile page in Safari on a Mac everything runs fine. However when I run it on an iPad/iPod and select links on the page that are supposed to navigate to different pages it doesn't work. If I navigate directly to any given page (e.g., index.html#PageId), it works, but if I select a link, the hash tag does not get appended to the URL and the displayed page doesn't change. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you should post a code sample so that somebody could point out that you link incorrectly ;) Also - it looks like you are not using the latest version of JQM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be some the result of some buried code that was intercepting the touch events and handling them incorrectly.